# Queryset Entres fechas Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta entre dos fecha es decir:

```
where fecha_creacion >= fecha_iniciar and fecha_creacion <= fecha_final.
```

Este es mi código Django:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        fecha_inicio=str(request.POST.get('fecha_inicio', False))
        fecha_final=str(request.POST.get('fecha_final', False))
        fecha_inicio = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_inicio, 
        '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        fecha_final = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_final, 
        '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 

        Encuesta.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__gt=fecha_inicio,
        fecha_creacion__lt=fecha_final, jefe_unidad_id__isnull=False).
        order_by('id'):
```

Tambien he probado esto:

```
    Encuesta.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__range(fecha_inicio,fecha_final), 
    jefe_unidad_id__isnull=False).order_by('id'):
```

Me obtiene los datos no incluyendo el día inicial y final de la consulta, es decir esta haciendo esto:

```
where fecha_creacion > fecha_iniciar and fecha_creacion < fecha_final.
```

Como puedo hacer para que me tome el día inicial y final de la consulta?

Django 1.8
Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar el operador de consulta `gte` (*greater thar or equal to*) en lugar de `gt` (*greater than*) y `lte` en lugar de `lt` para incluir el valor en cuestión.

Te quedaría algo asi:

```
Encuesta.objects.filter(
    fecha_creacion__gte=fecha_inicio, 
    fecha_creacion__lte=fecha_final, 
    jefe_unidad_id__isnull=False).order_by('id')
```

PD: Estoy asumiendo que Encuesta tiene fields del tipo `DateTimeField` y no `DateField`. En cualquier caso, deberías incluir esta definición en tu pregunta para mayor información, porque podrías estar mesclandolos y eso produce comportamientos ad-hoc [según la documentación de `Django`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range)